# Include specific form from template Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have an html template with 3 forms in it. I need to reuse the controller and two forms from this template in another page. How can I achieve this?

**mainForm.htm**

```
<form ng-show="activeTab == 'form1'" name="form1" id="form1">
<p> this is form1 </p>
</form>

<form ng-show="activeTab == 'form2'" name="form2" id="form2">
    <p> this is form2 </p>
</form>

<form ng-show="activeTab == 'form3'" name="form3" id="form3">
    <p> this is form3 </p>
</form>
```

**subForm.htm**

```
<div ng-include="mainForm.htm">
<p> need only form1 and form3 from mainForm.htm here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is for show only one form by page. Try creating each form in separate view and `ng-include` as you need.

Comment: @JuanjoSalvador I was thinking about doing like this. but is there any other fix for this for the present situation?

Comment: Better option is to create a separate directives for each HTML form. So you will get free hand to use whichever directive you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented in your question, best way is to creating each form in separate view and `ng-include` as you need.

**form1.html**

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" id="form1">
 <!-- your form code -->
</form>
```

(And repeat this example for each form)

**mainForm.html**

```
<div ng-show="activeTab == form1">
  <div ng-include="form1.html"></div>
</div>
<!-- Each other form you want -->
```